# Seeking Exonyms dataset?

Tags: data

Does anybody know some Exonyms dataset?

What I would like to find is a list of Europe cities/toponyms in different languages where all the cities refer to the same.

Example:
London, Londra, Londres, Londino --> All refer to London

I don't know if this exists.
The idea is to find some database that I can download, in order to make as authomatic as possible, and not copy-paste it.

I've searched in the net, but have not found anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is captured in the alternate names field in the [GeoNames](http://geonames.org) database. You'll need the [alternatenames.zip](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/alternateNames.zip) file that contains lists of names like:

> 2020600   2634688 fr  Gare de Londres Waterloo
>   2020602   2634688 de  London Waterloo Station
>   2020603   2634688 pl  Waterloo Station
>   2020604   2634688 fi  Waterloon rautatieasema
>   2020605   2634688 nl  Waterloo Station
>   2020606   2634688 pt  Estação Waterloo
>   2428532   2634688 en  London Waterloo station
>   3172599   2634688     Waterloo Station
>   5811502   2634688 abbr    WAT              8435719    2634688 iata    QQW
>   8435720   2634688 link    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Waterloo_station

for any place in the full database that has an alternate name.